# What happens to my deleted Trello cards?

Tags: trello, security, delete

I am trying to push Trello for adoption within my organisation, but there is concern from higher up about the deletion of data.

Are cards logically deleted (ie setting `deleted=true`) or are they really deleted from the server?

As I understand it [boards](https://trello.com/c/dapVABdL) and [lists](https://trello.com/c/c2dHduk1) can only be archived for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cards can be archived too. This is the preferred way to handle completed cards/boards.   Archived items are hidden from board view but can still be searched for and returned from the archive if desired.

When actually deleting a card the system reports "There is no undo" with this action.

Adoption by our team members (< 20 in our case) was very quick (less than a month) once we showed them all the basics.